# How do I loop a piece of code (have tried for, doesn't seem to work for me)

Tags: python, loops, repeat

I'm looking for a way to loop the code below... so that it'll go through and print the first sentence, then the second sentence over and over until one entity's health drops to zero.

From my research (bearing in mind I'm a knucklehead) the 'for' function seems to only work with single words/numbers... but perhaps I'm wrong.

CODE:

```
if sentence == 1:
  print ("The" + " " + enemy_1 + " " + random.choice(attack_verb) + " " + main_character + " " + "with its" + " " + random.choice(enemy_1_weapon))
  enemy_1_health -= 20
  print (enemy_1_health) 
  sentence = 0
  
if sentence == 0:
  print (main_character + " " + random.choice(attack_verb) + " " + "the" + " " + enemy_1 + " " + "with his" + " " + random.choice(main_character_weapon))
  enemy_1_health -= 20
  print (enemy_1_health)
  sentence = 1

#And then repeat and repeat over and over :)
```

Comment: Have you looked through [the documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) or any of the [many](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) [available](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) [articles](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/09/loops-and-control-statements-an-in-depth-python-tutorial/) on this topic?

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this

```
while enemy_1_health > 0:
    if sentence == 1: 
        print ("The" + " " + enemy_1 + " " + random.choice(attack_verb) + " " + main_character + " " + "with its" + " " + random.choice(enemy_1_weapon)) 
        enemy_1_health -= 20 
        print(enemy_1_health) 
        sentence = 0
    
    if sentence == 0: 
        print (main_character + " " + random.choice(attack_verb) + " " + "the" + " " + enemy_1 + " " + "with his" + " " + random.choice(main_character_weapon)) 
        enemy_1_health -= 20 
        print(enemy_1_health) 
        sentence = 1
```

Comment: Makes so much sense, I knew there was a simple solution, thanks heaps!

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the loop to happen **while** a particular condition is true, rather than **for** each item in a list/range/etc, you want a `while` loop:

```
while enemy_1_health > 0:
    print(f"The {enemy_1} {random.choice(attack_verb)} {main_character}  with its {random.choice(enemy_1_weapon)}")
    enemy_1_health -= 20
    print(enemy_1_health) 
    
    print(f"{main_character} {random.choice(attack_verb)} the {enemy_1} with his {random.choice(main_character_weapon)}")
    enemy_1_health -= 20
    print(enemy_1_health)
```

Note that you don't need the `if sentence` stuff because you're always setting `sentence` in such a way as to make it equivalent to `if True`, at which point you can dispense with the whole thing.

Here's an example of how you could use a `for` loop to iterate over the different attack scenarios:

```
while enemy_1_health > 0:
    for attacker, attacker_pronoun, victim, weapons in [
        (f"The {enemy_1}", "its", main_character, enemy_1_weapon),
        (main_character, "his", f"the {enemy_1}", main_character_weapon),
    ]:
        print(f"{attacker} {random.choice(attack_verb)} {victim} with {attacker_pronoun} {random.choice(weapons)}")
        enemy_1_health -= 20
        print(enemy_1_health)
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks so much!